# Unexpected duplicated primary key on delete -> save combination in different transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to save new instance of very big entity. To do it I delete this entity with propagation=REQUIRED_NEW and then saves new entity for the same project in new transaction. As result of this operations I receives exception, that one of the related entites can't be save, because rhe same primary key is still in db. Unexpectedly, all entities (including entity mentioned in exception) save correctly. Why I receives this error and what should I do to fix it?
Receives error on Link entity (when deletes assotiated entity and then creates new one).

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "uk_2ds6ia48b1ea56u8qpv52qukq"
  Подробности: Ключ "(project_id)=(b0d576ff-bca8-4ea3-9c1e-04db309dccb3)" уже существует.] [insert into schemes (offset_x,offset_y,project_id,version,zoom) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into schemes (offset_x,offset_y,project_id,version,zoom) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [null]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:269)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:243)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.repository.SchemeRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.save(<generated>)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.service.data.SchemeService.save(SchemeService.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.service.data.SchemeService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.save(<generated>)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.service.facade.SchemeFacade.updateProjectScheme(SchemeFacade.java:49)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.service.facade.SchemeFacade.save(SchemeFacade.java:33)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.controller.SchemeController.save(SchemeController.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "uk_2ds6ia48b1ea56u8qpv52qukq"
  Подробности: Ключ "(project_id)=(b0d576ff-bca8-4ea3-9c1e-04db309dccb3)" уже существует.] [insert into schemes (offset_x,offset_y,project_id,version,zoom) values (?,?,?,?,?)]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.performInsert(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.execute(MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2780)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:739)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy121.persist(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy121.persist(Unknown Source)
    at ru.mpei.dcse.repository.SchemeRepository.save(SchemeRepository.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "uk_2ds6ia48b1ea56u8qpv52qukq"
  Подробности: Ключ "(project_id)=(b0d576ff-bca8-4ea3-9c1e-04db309dccb3)" уже существует.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:275)
    ... 116 more
```

**Bad method** of facade class (without transaction). Block 4-7:

```
1 private void updateProjectScheme(Scheme receivedScheme, ProjectInfo projectInfo) {
2 
3         if (projectInfo.getScheme() != null) {
4             this.schemeService.delete(projectInfo.getId());
5             receivedScheme.setProjectInfo(projectInfo);
6             projectInfo.setScheme(receivedScheme);
7             this.schemeService.save(receivedScheme);
8         } else {
9             receivedScheme.setProjectInfo(projectInfo);
10            projectInfo.setScheme(receivedScheme);
11            this.schemeService.save(receivedScheme);
12        }
13    }
```

**schemeService.delete**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean delete(String projectId) {
        return this.repository.delete(projectId);
    }
```

**schemeRepository.delte**

```
public boolean delete(String projectId) {
        return this.entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Scheme s WHERE s.projectInfo.id = :projectId")
                .setParameter("projectId", projectId)
                .executeUpdate() > 0;
    }
```

**schemeService.save**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(Scheme scheme) {
        this.repository.save(scheme);
    }
```

**schemeRepository.save**

```
public void save(Scheme scheme) {
        this.entityManager.persist(scheme);
    }
```

**Scheme**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schemes")
@Getter@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Scheme implements SelfUpdatable<Scheme> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "offset_x")
    private double offsetX;

    @Column(name = "offset_y")
    private double offsetY;

    private double zoom;

    private double version;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "scheme",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<EquipmentNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "scheme",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private ProjectInfo projectInfo;
}
```

**ProjectInfo**

```
@Entity
@Getter@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "project_info")
public class ProjectInfo {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String owner;

    @Convert(converter =ListAttributeConverter.class)
    private List<String> applications;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "projectInfo",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Scheme scheme;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "projectInfo",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private CalculationsSettings settings;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<GeneratedScenario> generatedScenarios;
}
```

**Link**

```
@Entity
@Getter@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "links")
public class Link implements SelfUpdatable<Link> {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    private String alignmentType;

    private String sourceEquipmentId;

    private String sourcePortId;

    private String targetEquipmentId;

    private String targetPortId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "link", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Point> points;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "scheme_id")
    private Scheme scheme;
```

I tried to change propagation level, use repositories against services.

Answer (score 0):

You need flush, when you deleted your entity. because your external transaction is not yet committed when you save the entity and it is deleted only in the context of the first transaction.